# Design phase of a bluetooth chat app for Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, bluetooth

I need help with the modules needed to implement and design a bluetooth chat app for an android phone.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you haven't done any research yet...

You have [example of bluetooth chat application](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html) on official android developers site.

The example demonstrates all the fundamental Bluetooth API capabilites, such as:

- Scanning for other Bluetooth devices
- Querying the local Bluetooth adapter for paired Bluetooth devices
- Establishing RFCOMM channels/sockets
- Connecting to a remote device
- Transfering data over Bluetooth

Another great explanation is this [dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html).